# I have a label Starred Messages, that keeps a count of number of messages starred, as a person clicks on the button to Star the message

Tags: javascript, html

As a user clicks on the button Star Message! the counter should be increased to one and the value should be dynamically stored and displayed on the webpage. Also, if the person deselects, the value should be subtracted and now the value should return back to its original number.

```js
var button = document.querySelectorAll("button")[0];
button.addEventListener('click', function() {
  this.classList.toggle('btn-alt-color');

  if (button.getAttribute("data-text-swap") == button.innerHTML) {
    button.innerHTML = button.getAttribute("data-text-original");
  } else {
    button.setAttribute("data-text-original", button.innerHTML);
    button.innerHTML = button.getAttribute("data-text-swap");
  }
}, false);
```

```html
<div>
  <h2>Starred: </h2>
</div>

<figure class=frame id="box">
  <span class="helper"></span><img class="profile1" src="widows2.jpg" alt="my img" />
  <p>Twitter | Feb, 2017 <br><br> Message 1 from person Deep. His Favourite music genre is pop</p>
  <button class="btn-hold" data-text-swap=" Starred!">Star Message!</button>
  <figcaption id="text">Deep Mehta</figcaption>
</figure>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set a counter and toggle it when you add or remove the class 'btn-alt-color'. Please try the following changes.

```
  <div>
     <h2 id='starCounter' >Starred:</h2>
  </div>

  var star_count =0;

  var button = document.querySelectorAll(".frame button")[0];
  button.addEventListener('click', function() {

  if(this.classList.contains('btn-alt-color')){
    this.classList.remove('btn-alt-color');
    star_count--;
  } 
  else {
    this.classList.add('btn-alt-color');   
    star_count++;
  }
  console.log(star_count);
  document.getElementById("starCounter").innerText = "Starred: " +  star_count;

  if (button.getAttribute("data-text-swap") == button.innerHTML) {
    button.innerHTML = button.getAttribute("data-text-original");
  } else {
    button.setAttribute("data-text-original", button.innerHTML);
    button.innerHTML = button.getAttribute("data-text-swap");
  }
}, false);
```